# reload div content with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

here is the code  I am using :

```
 $('.label').load('page.php?id='+pageid);
```

I want to be able to refresh the div with class="label" only. I use load it works but places the whole page content inside that div. how do I reload only that part?

Comment: you want to load part div in page.php to div with class label?

Answer (score 1):

You should let the ajax response only be the part you wanted, if it returns the whole page, why not just refresh the page. Although `.load` supports to select the parts of the response with a suffixed selector expression.

Comment: no I dont want to refresh the whole page thats the whole point behind using ajax here. its an iframe and we dont want it to reload because when it reloads music stops. I know there is a way to reload just the div but I cant get it to work

Comment: Have you tried `$('.label').load('page.php?id='+pageid + ' #target');`?